# formatting HTML from arrays in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I've gone through 5-6 questions on SO before asking _ The other questions appear to refer to formatting all the data from complete JSON files _ This question is about formatting the elements of an array parsed from a JSON file _

The complete test page is online [here](https://inputforcolor.net/gameslib/libgames01.html)  but for the sake of brevity on this page I have shortened the JSON data _

```
{
    "PGRgames" : [
        {
            "id" : "Abzu",
            "fullName" : "Abzû",
            "PEGI" : 7,
            "platforms" : ["PS4"],
            "genres" : ["Adventure", "Simulation"],
            "image" : "img_Abzu.png",
            "details" : "ABZÛ is a beautiful underwater adventure that evokes the dream of diving. Immerse yourself in a vibrant ocean world full of mystery and bursting with colour and life."
        },
        {
            "id" : "AdventurePirates",
            "fullName" : "Adventure Time: Pirates Of The Enchridion",
            "PEGI" : 7,
            "platforms" : ["XBoxOne", "PS4", "Switch"],
            "genres" : ["Adventure", "Sandbox", "KIDS"],
            "image" : "img_AdventurePirates.png",
            "details" : "The Land of Ooo is underwater and it’s up to Finn and Jake to find out why.  Join our heroes as they explore the high seas."
        },
        {
            "id" : "KingdomCome",
            "fullName" : "Kingdom Come: Deliverance",
            "PEGI" : 18,
            "platforms" : ["XBoxOne", "XBoxOneX", "PS4"],
            "genres" : ["Action", "RPG"],
            "image" : "img_KingdomCome.png",
            "details" : "Massive realistic open world: Majestic castles, vast fields, all rendered in stunning high-end graphics. Solve quests in multiple ways, then face the consequences of your decisions."
        }
    ]
}
```

My JS code is _

```
<script>
let askHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
            askHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let gamesList = JSON.parse(askHTTP.responseText);
                    let output = '';
                    let PGRgames = gamesList.PGRgames;
                    for (let i = 0; i < PGRgames.length; i++) {
                        output += '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 padBox"><div class="gameBox center"><img src="media/' 
                        + PGRgames[i].image 
                        + '" /><div class="horizBuffer"></div>' 
                        + '<div class="center"><span class="fontBrand1 smallText"><strong>' + PGRgames[i].genres + '</strong></span></div>'
                        + '<div class="horizBuffer"></div>'
                        + '<div class="left"><span class="fontBlack text">' + PGRgames[i].details + '</span></div>'
                        + '<div class="horizBuffer"></div>'
                        + '<div class="center"><span class="fontBlack text"><strong>' + PGRgames[i].platforms + '</strong></span></div>'
                        + '</div></div>';  
                    }
                    document.getElementById('displayGames').innerHTML = output;
                }
            };
            askHTTP.open("GET", "js/PGRgames.json", true);
            askHTTP.send();

</script>
```

If you look at the content on the page I have linked to you'll see that **PGRgames.genres** & **PGRgames.platforms** have commas but no spaces between the array elements _ Also that the arrays are not conforming to the area they are supposed to be confined to _

Formatting these two arrays is specifically what my question refers to _ I'd be grateful for any assistance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .join() to format array to string.

```js
var array = ["foo", "bar", "tet"];

console.log('formatted:', array.join(', '));

console.log('tostring:', ''+array);
```

In your case replace `PGRgames[i].genres` with `PGRgames[i].genres.join(', ')` and other array outputs in similar manner.

Comment: That worked Rauli!
I used PGRgames[i].genres.join(' ') because I didn't want the comma _ 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you write this line:

```
PGRgames[1].platforms
```

and it is like writing this:

```
PGRgames[1].platforms.toString()
```

and what it does is just use the tostring of each element in the array and connect them with comma.

what you need to do is use join to tha array and format it as you need like this:

```
PGRgames[1].platforms.join(', ')
```